# Why had author used present time describing past events? (Quote inside)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read a "Treasure Island" book now and can't understand why had author used present time describing past events.

> Mr. Trelawney had taken up his residence at an inn far down the docks
>   to superintend the work upon the schooner. Thither we had now to walk,
>   and our way, to my great delight, **lay** along the quays and beside
>   the great multitude of ships of all sizes and rigs and nations. In
>   one, sailors were singing at their work, in another there were men
>   aloft, high over my head, hanging to threads that seemed no thicker
>   than a spider's.

Could you explain me, please, why here we read "lay", but not "laid"?

Comment: the prose is in the present

Comment: *Laid* is the past-tense form of *lay*, the transitive verb meaning "cause to lie, set"; but *lay* is used here as the past-tense form of *lie*, the intransitive verb meaning (in this case) "have the location".

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for respond! I get it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because lay is the simple past off lie (in this context).

> lie - **lay** - lain (the horizontal resting position)
>
> lay - laid - laid (to put something down)